# How is the clicks/day for community ads calculated?

Tags: support, bug, meta, per-site-meta, open-source-advertising

To me, it looks like the clicks/day on a stats page like [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2515) is calculated as the clicks, divided by the days from the "Created" timestamp. However, is that correct? "Created" refers to the date the ad was added, not to the day the ad reached the threshold of 6 votes.

#### Example

Consider an ad that was added at January 1, and reached the threshold of 6 votes at February 1. Since then, people clicked on it 60 times. It is now March 1.

The current system would say the clicks per day has to be calculated over January and February, therefore the clicks/day rate is ~1, 60/59. However, that isn't fair! In January, the ad couldn't be clicked. The clicks/day rate should be ~2, 60/28.

#### Note

Please note that with this change, you'd have to track if community ads don't get below the threshold as well: for example, when an ad reaches 6 votes, than gets below the 6, and then above the 6 again - the system should only count the periods it had 6 votes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly how the "Clicks per day" is calculated — from the creation date, even if it takes a long time to reach the 6 votes that are needed for the ad to be included in the rotation.  See [Open-source ads stats display Clicks per day below 6 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230156/open-source-ads-stats-display-clicks-per-day-below-6-votes).

Additionally, the stats appears to be reset when the question is moved, as per the observations on [Did open-source ads stop running?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251554/did-open-source-ads-stop-running) and [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014).