# Open-source ads stats display Clicks per day below 6 votes

Tags: feature-request, open-source-advertising

Now, I realise that the open-source community ads is a free service, and thank you for that, but it'd be nice if the "Clicks per day" stat was more useful in judging the effectiveness of the individual banners in attracting the clicks.

Right now, it would appear that "Clicks per day" is calculated from the time the original answer is made, and takes into account the zeros from all those days where the answer had less than 6 votes, and thus wasn't part of the rotation.  As such, unless the answer gets 6 votes in the first day and also never goes below 6 afterwards, the "Clicks per day" statistic is misleading.

Would it perhaps be possible to implement some improvements to the stats?